# When is vector bundle over toric variety a toric variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, toric-varieties

Is it true that a vector bundle over a toric variety is also a toric variety if and only if it splits? if so, how do we prove it?

This seems to be the content of a remark in Oda's Tata's lectures on torus embeddings, although the language is slightly different, and there's no proof.

Comment: What does it mean that a vector bundle splits?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, a direct sum of line bundles?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Indeed.

Comment: See the proof of Lemma 1.1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9911192.pdf

Comment: @WalterNeff Thanks

Comment: Actually, both the referenced arxiv paper and the book by Oda seem to deal with the projectivization, but not the vector bundle itself. E.g. is the Total space of $O(-1)+O(3) \to CP^1$ a toric variety?